# Why does this fan blade have a serrated edge?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

The title speaks for itself. I got this fan for free and I’m wondering why it has a serrated edge at the end?

For anyone curious, according to the sticker on it, it’s a Muffin XL MX2B3, 115V, 0.2A, 115CFM.

[image]

Comment: I think those are just added for style or like for trapping the birds who try to perch over there!

Comment: It could be about physics though! Who knows? So why close?

Comment: @descheleschilder yes it is physics. The serrations will create small streams, that will change the way the air slips around them. Then I thought of googling, as I am not good a fluid mechanics.

Comment: It's to reduce noise.

Comment: @descheleschilder I voted to close because, while the explanation can get into some good physics, the question itself is not asking about understanding any physics concepts. Indeed, a sufficient answer to how the question is right now essentially is just "to reduce noise". Even the posted answer doesn't really get into any physics as to why this design would reduce noise.

Answer (score 8):

It is done to reduce noise.

Googling I came upon [this experiment](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325085075_Reduction_of_Ceiling_Fan_Noise_by_Serrated_Trailing_Edge) .

> Six ceiling fan blade models with different types of trailing edge serrations were created and were simulated using commercial software in the present studies in order to investigate the effectiveness of various trailing edge serrations in reducing fan blade trailing edge noise. They were original, flat tip, serrated, rectangular, half flat tip and half rectangular half flat tip fan blades. The simulation results showed that the half flat tip fan blade had the best acoustical performance where it could obtain an overall noise reduction of 13.9(Formula presented.)dBA followed by rectangular fan blade with 10.9(Formula presented.)dBA, flat tip fan blade with 9.2(Formula presented.)dBA, half rectangular half flat tip fan blade with 5.0(Formula presented.)dBA and serrated fan blade with 4.7(Formula presented.)dBA.

Comment: See what I mean?

Comment: How did you find thát so quickly? Now I see why you have 173k!

Comment: I asked google for "serrated  edge fans"

Comment: How simple can it be...;)